# "Leaving website" alert

Tags: javascript, alert

I have the following href on my site:

```
a href="http://www.google.com" name="external" onclick="confirmExit(this.name)
```

I just can't figure out how to make user stay on my website if he/she doesn't want to leave by clicking "cancel" (incomplete code below).

```
function confirmExit(name){
    if(name == "external"){
        if(confirm("Go to external site?")){

        }
    }
}
```

jQuery/Ajax is not an option.

Comment: If user navigates out of your page, he very likely wants to leave your page...

Comment: Basically: `if (!confirm('foo')) { return false; }` and `onclick="return confirmExit();"`. Returning false from an onclick effectively disables the click.

Comment: Just stopping by to say I hate pop ups like this, and dont you dare rephrase the wording to say "Click cancel to stay on this site"

Comment: @tymeJV although, very rarely, they are useful (gmail, jsFiddle... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return false.

```
function confirmExit(name){
    if(name == "external"){
        if(!confirm("Go to external site?")){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want this to happen on all links, or even when the user closes the tab, check out [@megawac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789242/leaving-website-alert/22789302#22789302).

Comment: Supposing that the parameter `name` is actually set to "external", returning false from an event should prevent it from happening.

Comment: @Teemu I haven't tested this, but returning false on the click, should prevent the click event from occurring, which should in turn prevent the onload event to happening right?

Comment: This works like a charm as i only want the popup for hrefs with name=external".

Answer (score 2):

Use [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) to show a confirm dialog before a user leaves the page

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
   if(true) { //display confirm dialog?
       return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
   }
});
```

Comment: jquery/ajax not an option to OP

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function. I suggest you to use this:

```
$(function () {
     $('a[name="external"]').click(function () {
         if (!confirm("Go to external site?")) {
            event.preventDefault();
         }
     });
});
```

If you use this, you don't need to add onclick="confirmExit(this.name)" to everything. Just add the above and your work will be done.

You can do this if you want behaviour of JSFiddle:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return "Are you sure you want to leave the page?"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `return false` inside the `confirmExit()` function and also use `return` at inline javascript like

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" name="external" onclick="return confirmExit(this.name)">Some Link</a>
                                  //Use return here also ---^
```

**JS**

```
function confirmExit(name){
    if(name == "external"){
        if(!confirm("Go to external site?")){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLYc4/)